# Power Automate Disapproves of my CVS file if base64ToString is used

Tags: power-automate

I am attempting a Power Automate tutorial that is intended to read a CSV file into a SharePoint List.  The way it is being done is to create a new Power Automate flow and pick the "Instant cloud flow" option and choose to use the "Manually trigger a flow" as the type.  We set up the first step of the flow to request the input data in the form of a CSV file from the user.

Then we add a step. This step is a Compose Data Operation which uses the base64ToString expression. The input to the base64ToString() expression, we add the Dynamic Content and I picked "Upload CSV".

I should mention at this point that my UI is a little different from the UI of the tutorial. I believe we are using different versions of Power Automate. The instructor had a button "Upload CSV" but I had to select this option from a list.

This screen shot shows the code that the generated when the instructor clicked on "Upload CSV".

[image: (pic)]

Notice that the generated string contains what seems to be a part: ['contains(collection, value)'] but it is not sure since we only see a small part of this display.

My experience is different, it lacks this "contains" part:

[image: (pic2)]

I mention all this because it might have something to do with the error I get. When I try to test my flow, the error I get says:

> InvalidTemplate Unable to process template language exprfessions in
> action 'CSVData' inputs at line '0' and column '0'.  The template
> language function 'base64ToString' expects its parameter to ba a
> string.  The provided value is of type 'Object'. Please see
> https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#base64ToString for usage details.

The webpage segment mentioned in the error message ( https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#base64ToString ) has an example where the base64-encoded string, "aGVsbG8=" is converted to the string "hello". This might be my problem. I am not sure if this csv file is base64. So, how to I check this and how to I ensure it is converted? Also, what should I make of the missing part of the command I have mentioned?

Comment: The cut off bit is probably `['content']`